# JavaScript Object Literal Notation Internal Variable Pointing

Tags: javascript, scope

I have an array of variables.
And I want one variable to equal the previous one. 
For example:

```
var myVars = {
    var1: "test",
    var2: var1
};

alert(myVars.var2);
```

*//output: var1 is not defined*

Any thoughts? I'm sure this is some sort of variable scope limitation.
I would like to hear otherwise.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot refer to the same [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_Object_Initializers) in an expression without using a function, I would recommend you to use the equivalent syntax:

```
var myVars = {};

myVars.var1 = "test",
myVars.var2 = myVars.var1;
```

Comment: Perfect thanks.
I actually resorted to this method.
I was just hoping my above mentioned method would work.
Guess not!

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
var myVar = "test";

var myArr = {
    var1: myVar,
    var2: myVar
}
```

Comment: I am trying to keep all variables inside a single object for name-space reasons. This does not work in my situation.

Comment: Right in that case you need to wrap all necessary variables in an object, like what CMS suggested. Just a note that you can also declare the array as object:

var myVars = new Object();
myVars.var1 = "test";
myVars.var2 = myVars.var1;

Comment: What array?  There are no arrays being used here.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myVars = {
    var1: "test",
    var2: this.var1
};
```

perhaps?

Comment: `this` is bound to the function-context, has nothing to do with the `myVars` instance